# Exclude a value if its more than 2SDs above/below the mean

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to exclude values which are two times Standard deviation above/below the mean in Excel. The data set is quite large. Any function in Excel or formula that i could use to do it automatically? Please note the Version of Excel is 2007. Would be best to clear the those cells

Comment: ***UNCLEAR*** if you have a column of values, do you want the outliers **cleared** or the cells **removed**???

Comment: @Gary'sStudent have the outlier cleared

Comment: I would do this in two steps. You generally dont want to simply delete data even if you need to ignore it. =If(Cell < STDev*2, True, False)  then you can filter by the return value.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have data in column **B** like:

[image]

*(the outliers are clearly marked)*

Running this little macro:

```
Sub OutlierKiller()
    Dim I As Long, N As Long, wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim U As Double, L As Double, v As Double
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    U = wf.Average(Range("B:B")) + 2 * wf.StDev_S(Range("B:B"))
    L = wf.Average(Range("B:B")) - 2 * wf.StDev_S(Range("B:B"))

    For I = 1 To N
        v = Cells(I, 2).Value
        If v >= U Or v <= L Then Cells(I, 2).Clear
    Next I
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

You will need to adjust the code to match your data structure.